# Haskell how to break file into multiple files

Tags: haskell

I am just learning haskell and I want to do a very simple program that takes one big file and splits it in multiple files when there is a empty line.

```
Line 1: skdjsakjadsldas
Line 2: sadjkndasjkdsajk
Line 3: sadojdadjisod
Line 4:
Line 5: asdjdashjkda
Line 6: asdiadsjidji
```

The file above would become two files, one with the first 3 lines and the second with the last 2 lines. To do this I made the following function:

```
consumeLines :: Handle -> Handle -> IO ()
consumeLines handleRead handleWrite = do
    result <- hIsEOF handleRead
    unless result $ do
    contents <- hGetLine handleRead
    when (contents /= "") $ do 
        hPutStrLn handleWrite contents 
        consumeLines handleRead handleWrite
```

The idea would be to give a Handler with where I am in the file and another with a file where I am going to write the current info. My question is if there is any smarter way to do this? I am a little bit afraid of using `hGetContents` and other methods, because I might screw up loading the entire file in my machine. This is quit a bit puzzling because at each step I have to create a new file to write the lines. So any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conventional way to break down this problem in Haskell would be:

1. Load the input file
2. Split the input into lines
3. Group the lines into paragraphs by blank lines
4. Produce a file name for each paragraph
5. Write each paragraph’s lines to the corresponding file

This is a suitable problem for lazy I/O. For #1, you can simply use `readFile`, which produces a string that will lazily read the file on demand as you traverse it:

```
getParagraphs :: FilePath -> IO [String]
getParagraphs path = do
  input <- readFile inputHandle
  -- …
```

> I am a little bit afraid of using `hGetContents` and other methods, because I might screw up loading the entire file in my machine.

This is a legitimate concern! If your code retains a reference to the whole input string from `readFile` or `hGetContents`, it will keep the whole file so far in memory, rather than just keeping around the portions that are necessary. This is a reason to avoid lazy I/O in larger programs, where it’s easier to make that mistake, but here the program is small enough that we can easily verify it.

For #2 and #3, splitting the file into lines and paragraphs, you can then just use the pure `lines` and `groupBy` functions!

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (groupBy)

getParagraphs :: FilePath -> IO [String]
getParagraphs path = do
  input <- readFile path
  pure $ splitParagraphs input

  -- Or: getParagraphs path = splitParagraphs <$> readFile path
  -- Or: getParagraphs path = fmap splitParagraphs (readFile path)
  -- Or: getParagraphs = fmap splitParagraphs . readFile

splitParagraphs :: String -> [String]
splitParagraphs
  = map unlines               -- Concatenate back into paragraphs
  . filter (not . any null)   -- Remove runs containing empty lines
  . groupBy ((==) `on` null)  -- Group empty and non-empty lines
  . lines                     -- Split into lines
```

Generally speaking it’s considered good style to confine I/O to just the parts of a program that do…well, input and output! Most of the actual computation can be done in pure code.

Then, separately, you can generate the list of file paths (#4) to write the paragraphs to, and simply call `writeFile` (#5) for each one, using a `for_` traversal:

```
import Data.Foldable (for_)

writeFiles :: FilePath -> Int -> String -> [String] -> IO ()
writeFiles prefix startIndex extension contents = do
  for_ (zip paths contents) $ \ (path, content) -> do
    writeFile path content
  where
    paths = map makePath [startIndex ..]
    makePath i = concat [prefix, show i, ".", extension]
```

Or even better, you can use a monadic `zipWith`, in particular `zipWithM_` to avoid accumulating a list of results, since the `writeFile` actions all return the dummy unit `()` value:

```
import Control.Monad (zipWithM_)

-- …
writeFiles prefix startIndex extension contents
  = zipWithM_ writeFile paths contents
  where
    -- …
```

Then you can simply hook these up to each other in your main program.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  paragraphs <- readParagraphs "input.txt"
  writeFiles "output" 1 "txt" paragraphs    -- output1.txt, output2.txt, &c.

  -- Or: readParagraphs "input.txt" >>= writeFiles "output" 1 "txt"
```

(I’ve just used `FilePath` and constant files for illustration; it’s fairly straightforward to adapt this to use `Handle`s and dynamic inputs instead.)

In this case you can have confidence that the result of `readFile` isn’t needlessly being retained because each of its consumers, `splitParagraphs` and `writeFiles`, contain only a single linear traversal over the input.

However, in more complex cases, lazy I/O can make it easy to make resource mistakes, where you either retain a file’s contents longer than necessary, or keep a file `Handle` open longer than necessary, or worse, inadvertently *close* a `Handle` before you’re actually done using it!

The general solution to those problems is found in resource-aware *streaming* packages such as [pipes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes), [conduit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit), and [streaming](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming). These libraries can help you make guarantees about the resource usage of your program, while still interleaving I/O effects and pure data processing in a convenient way. Exploring each of these libraries would be an answer unto itself, though.

Comment: Just an extra question. When you say: 

**In this case you can have confidence that the result of readFile isn’t needlessly being retained because each of its consumers, splitParagraphs and writeFiles, contain only a single linear traversal over the input.**

Is there a rule of thumb to always know if when you read any kind of file, whether or not the content is going to be stored when you read lazily? You said about a linear tranversion, but the compiler can know this beforehand?

Comment: @JoaoBregunci: Unfortunately, the compiler can’t really help with this. Lazy I/O is based on “lying” to the type system with `unsafeInterleaveIO :: IO a -> IO a` to “hide” I/O behind a thunk. *Fortunately*, since it’s based on lazy evaluation, the techniques to avoid space leaks with lazy I/O are the *same* as those to avoid space leaks in general: 1. paying careful attention to data dependencies, 2. profiling, and 3. using `!` on fields (or `StrictData`), `BangPatterns` on patterns (or `Strict`), `seq`, and strict functions (`$!`, `foldl'`, `modifyIORef'`, &c.) as needed to fix memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with this:

```
main = readFile path >>= return . zip [1..] . splitFile >>= writeNthFile path
```

Then just implement splitFile and writeNthFile.

Comment: ```splitFile = filter (/= "\n") . fmap unlines . groupBy (\a b -> (a == "") == (b == "")) . lines ```

Comment: ```writeNthFile path (n, t) = writeFile (path <> show n) t```

Comment: Nice alternative to my groupBy argument in the other answer: (on (==) null)